# Expect go to next spawn of incorrect username or password

Tags: expect

I have a little problem when coming to expect.
I have used it for few years now with good resaults, but now i had incorrect password so the script stops running to the end.

I have used expect on linux to reboot CCTV cameras at my company with cron. It has worked well, until i upgraded few of my cameras to newer model and then it was wrong username and password that was default. I did not notice it until i was looking at my logs that expect stoped to run with the password error. So i did dig around a little and wanted just to send ctrl-C to abort the connection and go to next spawn, but so far no luck. I have tried many different methods but none work so far.

```
spawn telnet $11
expect {
"unable to connect to remote host:" { }
"login:" {
send "username\r"
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
expect {
"wrong username or password"
send "\003" }
expect "#"
send "shutdown -r now\r"
expect "#" 
send "exit\r"
expect "Connection closed by foreign host." }
}
Spawn telnet $12
```

the result is that instead of going to spawn telnet 12 it just goes to end of file.

Anyone that can answer my question ?

Answer (score 0):

This is why indenting your code is important. You have this:

```
spawn telnet $11
expect {
    "unable to connect to remote host:" { }
    "login:" {
        send "username\r"
        expect "password:"
        send "$password\r"
        expect {
            "wrong username or password"
            send "\003" 
        }
        expect "#"
        send "shutdown -r now\r"
        expect "#" 
        send "exit\r"
        expect "Connection closed by foreign host." 
    }
}
```

In particular, this bit is wrong:

```
    expect {
        "wrong username or password" 
        send "\003" 
    }
```

This is what expect *actually* sees, because expect wants an "action" block for each pattern, except for the last pattern:

```
    expect {
        "wrong username or password" send 
        "\003" 
    }
```

This is because of the way Tcl is a word-oriented language.
So, you have 2 patterns, "wrong user..." or "\003".

This is what you want:

```
    expect {
        "wrong username or password" {send "\003"}
        "#" {
            send "shutdown -r now\r"
            # do you really expect another prompt after rebooting?
            expect eof
        }
    }
```